# Extension of a function to function with larger domain.

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to find which of the pairs of functions f and g 
is g an extension of f?
(a)  f(x)= x  (0<=x

(b) f(x)= 1 (-1<=x<=1)
     g(x)= 1 (0<=x

(c) f(x)= sin x ( 0<=x<= 2 pie)
     g(x)= square root of
           (1-cos^2 x)                        (- infinity

My approach:-
(a) & (c) are such that g is an extension of f.
while (b) is not as the domain of f is not subset of g.
Is this answer and reasoning sufficient?
Also want to clear the idea about the definition:-

Suppose f and g are two functions with domains X and Y.
If X is
 subset of Y and if f(x)=g(x)
(x belongs to X), we say that g is an extension of f.

My question is:
Whether f should be equal to g for all x in X?

Comment: It seems you have not wrote down your answer for $(a), (b), (c)$? And yes, $f$ has to be equal to $g$ for all $x$ in $X$, in order that $g$ is called an extension.

Comment: Yes, There was some problem in posting the question, I edited twice and finally it worked.

Comment: There is no $g$ in (a). Your argument for (b) is correct. For (c), don't understand your domain for $g$ (-infinity to what?). Note also that $\sqrt{1- \cos^2 x}$ is NOT $\sin x$, but $|\sin x|$.

Comment: I dont know whats going wrong in my editing and posting.:-(

Comment: a) g(x)= |x| for x in R , (b) g(x)=1 (0<=x<infinity) . (c) domain for g(x) is R

Comment: For (a), you need to check whether $f(x) = g(x)$ on $x\ge 0$. For $(c)$ the answer is no, because $\sqrt{1-\cos^2} = |\sin x|$ is not the same as $\sin x$ on the domain $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: Well, i think for (a) f(x)=g(x) for all x in domain of f as x is taking non negative values itself and absolute value is non negative always.

Comment: Yes, perfect. ${}{}$